# Facebook API to access privacy and security settings

Tags: facebook, security, api, privacy

Is there a way to get security and privacy settings of a Facebook account? The app that's being designed will need to:

- login to a Facebook account,
- retrieve all privacy and security settings, and
- display the settings on a single page in a custom way.

I did a lot of online searching, checked the FB Developer's site, but found nothing relevant so far.

Answer (score 2):

there is the security_settings endpoint, I dont know that it will provide what you are looking for tho...  it is
`/me?fields=security_settings`

you can explore it at

[http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dsecurity_settings](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me?fields=security_settings)

Answer (score 0):

Things you can fetch via the API:

**The post visibility chosen by the user for your app:**

> SELECT name, value, description, allow, deny, networks, friends FROM
>   privacy_setting WHERE name = 'default_stream_privacy'

More details in the [privacy_setting FQL table documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting/)

**The user's HTTPS settings** (thanks to NappingRabbit for this one too):

> /me?fields=security_settings

Returns an object describing the security settings of the user, only HTTPS setting is enabled:

```
{
  "security_settings": {
    "secure_browsing": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }, 
  "id": "<USER ID>"
}
```

**The privacy settings associated with individual posts**
Returned when accessing the posts directly, or via the [Privacy FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy/)

An example of retrieving the settings directly:
`USERID_POSTID/?fields=privacy`:

```
privacy": {
    "description": "Friends, <community name>; Except: Restricted", 
    "value": "CUSTOM", 
    "friends": "ALL_FRIENDS"
  }, 
  "id": "POST ID HERE", 
  "created_time": "2012-10-18T02:49:59+0000"
}
```

There is no API access to the user's privacy settings on Facebook.com (except for content-level privacy as i mentioned above) and attempting to automate logins and crawl Facebook's interface retrieve them will likely trip security protections

Comment: I hate to revive an old post, but I think you're one of the few StackOverflow users who would know, and I don't know how to message you. I'm working on an iPhone app and hope to be able to change the privacy setting of posts on a user's wall. For example, I want to be able to go through my status updates in an app and select which ones I want to be private. Is this possible at all with the Facebook iOS SDK or Graph API? Is there a workaround? Thanks ahead of time! :)